# How to send a file using webView evaluateJavaScript method efficiently?

Tags: javascript, java, android, kotlin, webview

I built a web view app for opening pdfs. It has a file input button that when you click on it and select a pdf file, it loads the pdf.
It works fine but the problem is that I send bytes array to javaScript and this adds an extra step which slows down the loading process. It can't load big pdfs(30 mb or bigger).
When I was converting the app to android; first I tried Capacitor library. Capacitor also uses webview and it loads big pdfs very well but I had some other issues using it.(For saving the pdf in user's storage). I tried to have my own webview and this is my code.

```
 public fun openFileDialog() {//this method gets called when you click on the button
            val intent = Intent()
                .setType("application/pdf")
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            resultLauncher.launch(intent)
        }

    private var resultLauncher = 
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // There are no request codes
            result?.data?.also { uri ->
                var inputStream = this.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri.data!!)
                var byteArray = inputStream!!.readBytes()               
                myWebView.evaluateJavascript("renderPdfByKt(${JSONArray(byteArray)})",null)
            }

        }

    }
```

`
The renderPdfByKt method:

```
     function renderPdfByKt(val){
            renderPdf(new Uint8Array(val); // uses pdf.js to render html into the page
        }
```

Is there a better way like enabling file inputs in webView or sending file path to js and convert it to unit8array in js other than sending the whole file to js with evaluatejavaScript().

Comment: A WebView cannot display a pdf file. So you might first elaborate what you are doing or what should be done.

Comment: I know. I use pdf.js witch is a library for rendering pdfs.  It's working fine for smaller pdfs but not for bigger ones